# Rails: how are paths generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb

In Rails 3, when a scaffold is generated for instance for a 'Category' the will be a categories_path (and a edit_category_path(@category), ...) used in the erb views.

This is not a variable that can be found anywhere and probably is generated. However in my case, for a different entity, Article, I first generated the model and then the controller. Now when I try output an articles_path, I get a

> undefined method `articles_path' for #<#:0x000001019d1be0>

I cannot even use a `<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>` as this generates the same error.

What am I supposed to do?

My routings are like this:

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :articles
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As article lives in the category scope, you need to use **category_articles_path**.

Comment: Thanks that did it (together with vonconrad's hint)!

Answer (score 1):

The articles resource is within the categories scope, so the correct path to use would be `category_articles_path(@category)` or `edit_category_articles_path(@category, @article)`. To do this for your form_for, try:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @article]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I gave the answer tick to Toby, though, because he was first!